# What is the command that allows you to count the number of items in a listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox

I was coding a project where I display a hundred random numbers in a listbox, then I find the smallest number, the largest number, the range of the number set, and the number of even numbers. The catch is, I have to use a while loop. I need a way to stop the loop once the number of random numbers hits 100. Is there a simple command to extract this as an integer?

Comment: Create a variable, count up the number of elements, and stop when the count > 100? Not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Is [listbox].Items.Count what you're looking for?

Comment: Are you asking how to tell if the Listbox has more than 100 items or to stop once you've looked at 100 elements in the listbox? The solution depends on which you are looking for.

Comment: *I display a hundred random numbers in a listbox* does this mean the `listbox` has already been initialized/filled with the data or do you have to generate this numbers, add them to the `listbox` and then do the find-the-numbers processes?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of items in the Listbox as follows ,

```
While(ListBox1.Items.Count <=100)
{
  // Your Logic
}
```

To Find the Largest Number is,

```
//To Find Largest number
List<int>  listboxItems = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
listboxItems.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item));
}
int Largest =  listboxItems.Max();
```

Comment: This will loop forever unless OP is adding elements to the ListBox as he goes, which from the question it doesn't sound like he's doing. Either adding a counter variable or using a for loop would work better.

Comment: @ Sajeetharan, thanks! Is there a way to extract data from the listBox? For example, if I wanted to find the largest number, is there a command that incorperates listBox1.Item.(Something) > other integers? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want to go through some loop one hundred times?

```
int step = 0;
for(i=0; i < 100; i++)
{
  // Your Logic
}
```